# How to obtain sum of records in a key,value fashion using nativeQuery in CrudRepository?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I am getting an array-list as a return type with 0th index as an array. What i want is a key value pair segregation, where column name is the key and its value is the corresponding sum i obtained.

```
@Query(value = "
SELECT SUM(revenue_amount) AS revenue_amount
     , SUM(service_charge_amount) AS service_charge_amount 
  FROM event_stats 
 WHERE event_id = :event_id
", nativeQuery = true)
public ? findTicketTotalForAnEvent(@Param("event_id") String event_id);
```

What should be the return type ? And how to filter it further ?

Comment: It should be `List<Object[]>`. key -> `list.get(0)[0]`, value -> `list.get(0)[1]`

Comment: Actually, I am getting 2 summations. One is in [0]th place and the other one is in [1]st place. There is no key

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to use Projections, something like below would give you desired result.

Declare a static interface like below:

```
static interface TotalTicketsForEvent { 
    public Long getRevenueAmount();
    public Long getServiceChargeAmount();
}
```

Now your query should be:

```
@Query(value="SELECT SUM(revenue_amount) AS revenueAmount, SUM(service_charge_amount) AS serviceChargeAmount FROM event_stats WHERE event_id = :event_id", nativeQuery = true)
public List<TotalTicketsForEvent> findTicketTotalForAnEvent(@Param("event_id") String event_id);
```

You can use the interface methods to process the list further.